# Why is initial JSON object parseable, but object within it not?

Tags: json, ruby

I'm storing a config file in version control (GitLab) which contains information to be read by my ruby app.  This info is stored as an object containing objects containing objects.

(Update adding more detail and examples for clarity as requested...)

From within my app I can successfully GET the file (which returns the following JSON Object (some bits trimmed with `...` for readability):
`{"file_name"=>"approval_config.json", "file_path"=>"approval_config.json", "size"=>1331, "encoding"=>"base64", "content_sha256"=>"1c21cbb...fa453fe", "ref"=>"master", "blob_id"=>"de...915", "commit_id"=>"07e...4ff", "last_commit_id"=>"07e...942f", "content"=>"ogICAg...AgICB"}`

I can JSON parse the above object and access the `contents` property on that object.  The value of the `contents` property is a base64Encoded string containing the actual contents of my file in GitLab.  I can successfully decode this and see the JSON string stored in GitLab:

`"{"G000":{"1":{"max":"4000","name":"Matthew Lewis","id":"ord-matthewl","email":"matthew.lewis@companyx.com"},"2":{"max":"4000","name":"Brendan Jones","id":"ord-brendanj","email":"brendan.jones@companyx.com"},"3":{"max":"20000","name":"Henry Orson","id":"ord-henryo","email":"henry.orson@companyx.com"},"4":{"max":"10000000","name":"Chris Adams","id":"ord-chrisa","email":"chris.adams@companyx.com"}},"G15":{"1":{"max":"4000","name":"Mike Butak","id":"ord-mikebu","email":"mike.butak@companyx.com"},"2":{"max":"4000","name":"Joseph Lister","id":"ord-josephl","email":"joseph.lister@companyx.com"},"3":{"max":"20000","name":"Mike Geisler","id":"ord-mikeg","email":"mike.geisler@companyx.com"},"4":{"max":"10000000","name":"Samuel Ahn","id":"ord-samuela","email":"samuel.ahn@companyx.com"}}}"`

THIS string (above), I cannot JSON parse.  I get an "unexpected token at '{ (JSON::ParserError)" error.

While writing this update it occurs to me that this "un-parsable" string is simply what I put in the file to begin with.  Perhaps the method I used to stringify the file's contents in the first place is the issue.  I simply pasted a valid javascript object in my browser's console, JSON.stringify'd it, copied the result from the console, and pasted it in my file in GitLab.  Perhaps I need to use Ruby's JSON.stringify method to stringify it?

Based on feedback from @ToddA.Jacobs, I tried the following in my ruby script:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'base64'
data = RestClient.get 'https://gitlab.companyx.net/api/v4/projects/3895/repository/files/approval_config.json?ref=master', {'PRIVATE-TOKEN':'*********'}
# get the encoded data stored on the 'content' key:
content = JSON.parse(data)['content']
# decode it:
config = Base64.decode64(content)
# print some logs
$evm.log(:info, config)
$evm.log(:info, "config is a Hash? :" + config.is_a?(Hash).to_s) #prints false
$evm.log(:info, "config is a string? :" + config.is_a?(String).to_s) #prints true
hash = JSON.parse(config)
example = hash.dig "G000" "4" "id"
$evm.log(:info, "print exmaple on next line")
$evm.log(:info, example)
```

That last line prints:
`The following error occurred during method evaluation: NoMethodError: undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass  (drbunix:///tmp/automation_engine20200903-3826-1nbuvl) /usr/local/ lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/manageiq-password-0.3.0/lib/manageiq/password.rb:89:in 'sanitize_string'`

Comment: original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696459/why-is-there-a-lack-of-integrity-in-parsed-json-object?noredirect=1#comment112644119_63696459) closed by moderators due to need for more details or clarity.  Reposted here with examples and details.  Thanks

Comment: Your string is enclosed in `"..."` but also contains `"` which doesn't work.

Comment: @Stefan are you refering to `"content"=>"ogICAg...AgICB"`?  I added the `...` to protect actual values encoded.  When I share the decoded string I changed the actual names.

Comment: Here's the other funny thing: Although I can't parse that stringified object (the `"{"G000":{"1":{"max...` object, I can try access properties in it (e.g., `object["G15"]` and it doesn't return an error.  Nor does it return the value associated with that key.  Instead it returns the key itself, i.e., `G15`.

Comment: You have invalid quoting of your JSON.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs can you be more specific?  Do you mean in the string starting with `"{"G000":{"1":{"max`?

Comment: @mike_butak that's just how [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#5B-5D-method) works: `"foobarbaz"["bar"] #=> "bar"`

Comment: I would have expected all of the embedded double quotes inside the stringified JSON to be escaped: `\"`.

Comment: You don't need to use Ruby's JSON stringify. It's an interoperable format so you can generate it from any language.

Comment: Use `JSON.dump` don't write your own JSON.

Comment: Thanks folks. I don't get why Javascript's JSON object is printing invalid JSON. I tried in Node, having it write the JSON to a file.  Same result.

Comment: @tadman can you elaborate on what you mean about using JSON.dump.  You mean to create the json content in the file to begin with?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs as far as invalid json, I shared that string with a co-worker. He parsed it with PowerShell with no issue and restringified it.  Looks just like what I have.

Comment: @mike_butak You can't have leading/trailing double-quotes without escaping all the quotes inside. I'm happy that it's working for your friend, but that doesn't make it valid JSON or valid Ruby. Using jq confirms this, and reports `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8`. Fix your source formatting before assuming the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @ToddA.Jacobs. Sorry I should clarify I've tried removing the leading/trailing double-quotes AND escaping the characters in between.  I've tried about 12 different variations of adding/removing initial and final quotes, both single and double (with and without escapes on those) with and without escapes on quotes within the object.  It just won't parse.  The only format that dsn't throw a JSON parse error is this: "{\"key\":\"value\"}", but when parsed, it's a string still and I can't access key. I try parsing it AGAIN (I've seen that problem before) and I get error no such method.

Comment: I'm sure you'll agree that it's ridiculous that I'd have to manually create my own JSON. I am starting from a JS file with a valid JS object, which I JSON.stringify, and write to a file. That has zero escapes in it.

Comment: You've got too many moving parts. You're getting a string from a REST call; you're decoding payloads; you're trying to coerce a string into JSON; you're trying to access elements of your ersatz JSON. What you really need to do is stop trying to eat the elephant all at once. Pick any piece, and test *that*. Can you convert some known-good piece of JSON into a Ruby Hash? Can you access nested elements of that hash? Can you get a known-good JSON object from your REST endpoint? Can you successfully decode a known-good object that way? And so forth. This is where TDD/BDD would help you a lot.

Comment: THANK you @ToddA.Jacobs.  At least I don't feel crazy anymore.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs to isolate the issues one at a time, I did the following.  Grabbed "valid" JSON from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON, and saved to file on the same server where Ruby is running.  File.read("/tmp/valid.json") worked (can print contents). When I parse it I get the same errors as I got when parsing the content I pulled from REST. Also tried my package.json file from my functioning Node.js app, which HAS to be valid. Same errors when Ruby parses it.  Ruby can read and print these local json files, but can't parse 'em. By the way there are no escape chars within these json files?

Comment: What I mean is `JSON.dump` will *always* produce clean JSON output. Rolling your own JSON encoder will not necessarily. This looks like hand-crafted JSON and something went wrong during encoding because it isn't valid.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I got to the bottom of it. I was using a vendor-provided logging function, not the OOTB ruby print statement.  That logging function was unable to print the hash (even with to_s appened to it).  It was parsing all along.  THANK YOU for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by users on another post I opened: [Why can Ruby not parse local JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748477/why-can-ruby-not-parse-local-json-file?noredirect=1#comment112742126_63748477)

Ultimately the issue was not Ruby failing to parse my JSON.  Rather it was the logging function being unable to log the hash.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove Outer Quotes

Your input format *is* invalid: you're nesting unescaped double quotes, and somehow expecting that to work. Just leave off the outer quotes. For example:

```
require 'json'

json = <<~'EOF'
    {"G000":{"1":{"max":"4000","name":"Matthew Lewis","id":"ord-matthewl","email":"matthew.lewis@companyx.com"},"2":{"max":"4000","name":"Brendan Jones","id":"ord-brendanj","email":"brendan.jones@companyx.com"},"3":{"max":"20000","name":"Henry Orson","id":"ord-henryo","email":"henry.orson@companyx.com"},"4":{"max":"10000000","name":"Chris Adams","id":"ord-chrisa","email":"chris.adams@companyx.com"}},"G15":{"1":{"max":"4000","name":"Mike Butak","id":"ord-mikebu","email":"mike.butak@companyx.com"},"2":{"max":"4000","name":"Joseph Lister","id":"ord-josephl","email":"joseph.lister@companyx.com"},"3":{"max":"20000","name":"Mike Geisler","id":"ord-mikeg","email":"mike.geisler@companyx.com"},"4":{"max":"10000000","name":"Samuel Ahn","id":"ord-samuela","email":"samuel.ahn@companyx.com"}}}
EOF

hash = JSON.parse(json)

hash.dig "G000", "4", "id"
#=> "ord-chrisa"

hash.dig "G15", "4", "id"
#=> "ord-samuela"
```

Comment: I tried that (see update to post above).  Returned an error.  Did I misinterpret your guidance?

Comment: I tried removing the outer quotes, and I tried using the hash.dig syntax.  Not working.  A co-worker was able to parse my json without issue.